# How do I unit test Django Views?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, view

I want to begin integrating unit tests into my Django projects and I've discovered unit testing a view to be tricky because of the way Django implements views with functions.

For example, each function is a view/page in Django if the function has a URL.

How do I unit test Django views?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure how testing a view is tricky.

You just use the [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client).

Code coverage is easy.  You reason how how a URL request maps to a code path and make the appropriate URL requests.

You can, if you want, call the view functions "manually" by creating a Request object and examining the Response object, but this is too much work.

If you have doubts about your code coverage, that's a good thing.  It means you have code you can't easily map to a URL (which is all a user can ever see of a web application.)  If you have code that doesn't map to a URL, you should probably either (a) delete the code or (b) refactor it into a separate module.

We have lots of modules outside our view functions.  Our view functions import these modules.  We test these "outside the view function" modules with ordinary unittest.

---

Here's a typical structure.

```
some_big_product/
|-- __init__.py
|-- settings.py
|-- urls.py
|-- logging.ini
|-- other_global_files.py
|-- an_app_1/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- views.py
|   |-- tests.py <-- the generic Django testing 
|   |-- app_specific_module.py
|   |-- app_specific_package/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_app_specific_module.py <-- unittest 
|   |-- test_app_specific_package.py
|-- generic_module.py
|-- generic_package/
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- tests/
|   |-- test_this.py
|   |-- test_that.py
|   |-- test_all.py <-- not always practical
|-- scripts/
    |-- run_tests.sh
```

Comment: Hmm this could answer another question I have. How do you manage the directory structure when adding other modules in the django project/app hierarchy?

Comment: How might test_all.py work? I'm assuming I'd like to get everything into one big TestCase.TestSuite, and then run it. That way all test stats (passes & fails) are aggregated into a single output at the end. I can't decide whether I should be customising Django's "manage.py test" to run the extra unittests, or writing my own top-level test runner that incorporates Django's unit tests.

Comment: @Tartley:  First, try Django's `manage.py test`.  80% of the time, that's all you need.  If you have more complex RESTful web services (both as server and client of other services) or other modules outside the Django "typical" framework, then you may find that you can't simply use the Django testing framework and need to write additional `unittest` tests.  In this case, you're `test_all` invokes Django's and then invokes the unit tests.  Don't tweak their code.  Just write the simplest script you can write that uses theirs and uses unittest.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Mr Lott! You are right that we've started to place tests outside the usual locations that Django looks for tests (ie. a top-level 'acceptancetests' directory (tests user-visible functionality which straddles applications) and low-level unit tests which live all over the repo, not just within Django applications 'test.py' script.  I've hacked together a quick script that searches all modules in the tree looking for subclasses of TestCase, puts them into a single suite, and runs it. This does catch Django test cases, as well as our own non-django unit tests.

Comment: @Tartley: "quick script that searches all modules in the tree looking for subclasses of TestCase," should already be part of `unittest`.  Go carefully here, since many of these features are already available.

Comment: Thanks. I can't just use unittest discovery from the command-line, because the django tests need django setup before they are invoked, but you are right that I should probably be using unittest discovery from within my script. I wanted to do it myself so I could allow the user more freedom in specifying test package/module/class/method names on the command-line, e.g. with a glob that matches any of the above, but on reflection perhaps I should use unittest discovery and then filter the results from that afterwards. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately the provided link to the test client is not working anymore. The correct location is now https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#module-django.test.client

Answer (score 2):

django.test.client should have everything you need for basic unit testing of the view. I also really like [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) and [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for testing the full stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [tddspry](http://github.com/42/tddspry/tree/master) - collection of helpers to test Django with nosetests and twill. Nose also have coverage plugin which generate pretty reports of the coverage.